# Putting parameters in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have many parameters in a stored procedure but I am concerned about using 2 of them in a select query,

E.g. a user sends `FloorNo`, `DateFrom`, `DateTo` to the stored procedure and get back records between date range for specific floor. But what I want is to select `DateFrom` and `DateTo` too.

My query is:

```
Select 
   Complainants.FloorNo, 
   Count(Complaints.Complainant_ID) as TotalComplaints 
from 
   Complainants 
inner join 
   Complaints ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
where
   REPLACE(convert(varchar, EntryDateTime, 106), ' ','/') >= @DateFrom
   AND
   REPLACE(convert(varchar, EntryDateTime, 106), ' ','/') <= @DateTo
```

but I want to include `DateFrom`, `DateTo` in the result set. I tried but it's not working

Comment: can u update the query which is not working...

Comment: I assume EntryDateTime is a datetime data type.  Is there some reason you don't pass the parameter values as a strongly-typed datetime parameter instead of as strings?  That will avoid the need for REPLACE.  An index on the EntryDateTime column cannot be used efficiently (requiring a scan) when you apply functions to the column in the WHERE clause.  The index can be used if you compare EntryDateTime to datetime parameters directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put it this way

```
Select Complainants.FloorNo, Count(Complaints.Complainant_ID) as TotalComplaints, @DateFrom AS DateFrom, @DateTo AS DateTo from Complainants 
       inner join Complaints
       ON Complainants.ComplainantID = Complaints.Complainant_ID
       where
       REPLACE(convert(varchar, EntryDateTime, 106), ' ','/') >= @DateFrom
       AND
       REPLACE(convert(varchar, EntryDateTime, 106), ' ','/') <= @DateTo
```

Comment: no it doesn't show anything, atleast not in RDLC report

Comment: How about binding directly the Parameters on the report itself?